# Programmatically opening workbooks breaks events

Tags: excel, vba

I am generating a prompt list to open workbooks. However, doing so makes the event handlers in the opened .xlsm not run at all, but opening the same file directly through Windows Explorer works as expected.

I have tried adding

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

In different parts of the code

```
Public Sub Shft_O_open_misc_logs()
    Dim openlog As Integer
    Dim path As String, found As String
    Dim rOnly As Boolean
    Dim wb As Workbook

    On Error GoTo leave

    openlog = CInt(InputBox("Enter the numeric code for the log to open" & _
                vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "[1] Grievance Log" & vbNewLine & _
                "[2] Watch Box Counter" & vbNewLine & _
                "[3] SF-813" & vbNewLine & _
                "[4] OLD SF-813" & vbNewLine & _
                "[5] Pending Consolidations" & vbNewLine & _
                "[6] Recipient Group Listing" & _
                vbNewLine, _
                "Open log"))

    Select Case openlog
        Case 1:
            path = "...\Grievance Log.xlsm"
        Case 2:
            path = "...\Watchbox Counter.xlsm"
        Case 3:
            path = "...\SF813.xlsm"
        Case 4:
            path = "...\813 Log FY15-16-17-18.xlsm"
        Case 5:
            path = "...\Workload Management Toolkit*"
            rOnly = True
        Case 6:
            path = "...\Recipient Groups.xlsm"
        Case Else:
            GoTo leave
    End Select

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=path, ReadOnly:=rOnly)
    wb.Activate
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized

leave:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps look at this, there is a difference between workbook events and Application events, once you open that workbook read-only there could be an issue with the code understanding where things are taking place.  https://superuser.com/a/1029107

Comment: Opening a workbook via code does not run any workbook_open events in the workbook being opened - you will need to call those yourself.  EDIT - that might apply only to Auto_Open...

Comment: No, all events are broken. Anything in sheet change will not run despite changing cells in the sheet. And running it in read-only happens in one case where there are no events.

Comment: Is the File Path a Trusted Location, or are Macros automatically being disabled for the Workbook?

Comment: The path is trusted. It is strange, though. I open .xlsm in other code and the events like before close still work. However, this particular sub breaks events.

Comment: As a workaround It might work if you call the workbook directly using CreateObject

CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open("C:\path-to-docs\SF813.xlsm")

Comment: Could it be you have set ScreenUpdating = False elsewhere and it appears to be doing nothing. ReadOnly should not be a cause of the problem - works for me with ReadOnly as True or False in a simple test file